# Send and Receiving money based on account number / sort code

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment-processing, opayo

I'm looking for a payment provider (or any other method) of taking payments with credit card details. Then immediately transfer the money to one of possibly hundreds of bank accounts (This has to be based on bank account number and sort code).

Does anyone know of a provider or other way of doing this?

Comment: Have you tried speaking to your merchant provider (bank or similar)? Your account-and-sort-code requirement sounds (to me anyway) pretty specialist; they may be able to help?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you want to integrate two technologies, a credit card processing service for bringing money in and then an [ACH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_Clearing_House) API for sending money out.

You can either look for two discreet services for doing this such as [WePay](http://www.wepay.com) and [BancBox](http://www.bancbox.com) (cc and ACH respectively) or look at integrated services that provide both technologies such as [Balanced](https://www.balancedpayments.com) (whom I work with).

Then depending on if you're taking the payments in directly on your site or not, you should be able to map from a card to a bank account and shoot the money out to the correct bank account via the ACH API once you've received the funds.

One thing to consider is that there is a 30 day window for disputes on credit cards, called a [chargeback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chargeback), and you could be liable for this and caught short if you've already sent the money on its way to the recipient.

Comment: I just noticed you're not in the USA so the sites I posted may be less helpful. The general concept should still be the same as well as the chargeback information. Best of luck.